# How to delete java.util.prefs storage on a Mac?

Tags: java, macos, preferences

I'm using the java.util.prefs package to store some information entered by users. My understanding, based on documentation and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675864/where-are-java-preferences-stored-on-mac-os-x) is that the actual (user node) preferences are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/`, in a file named after the package. So far, this all checks out: Whenever I store some data in the node, a file in this directory is created and using the command line tool `plutil`, I can inspect it and find the stored data.

However: When I delete the file, and restart my program, the data is still there. I couldn't find anything about that in the documentation or source code. Any help appreciated.

The following code demonstrates the behaviour, see command line session below:

```java
package de.unistuttgart.ims.PreferencesTest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.prefs.Preferences;

public class Main {

    Preferences preferences = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(Main.class);

    static Main app;

    static String KEY = "KEY";
    static String DEFAULTVALUE = "DEFAULTVALUE";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        app = new Main();
        app.doStuff();

    }

    public void doStuff() throws IOException {
        System.err.println("Retrieving value:");
        System.err.println(preferences.get(KEY, DEFAULTVALUE));

        System.err.println("Setting value:");
        char ch = (char) System.in.read();
        preferences.put(KEY, String.valueOf(ch));

    }

}
```

Command line session:

```
$ java de.unistuttgart.ims.PreferencesTest.Main
Retrieving value:
DEFAULTVALUE
Setting value:
5
$ rm ~/Library/Preferences/de.unistuttgart.ims.plist
$ java de.unistuttgart.ims.PreferencesTest.Main
Retrieving value:
5
Setting value:
4
```

How can this be? Or: Where else are preferences stored?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/342010/36809

Comment: That was fast and helpful, thanks!